# How to enter special characters like “\” in oracle database INSERT STATEMENT?

Tags: sql, oracle, escaping, sql-insert

UPDATE:
I've just figured out that the problem wasn't coming from the backslash. The problem is a single quotation mark problem. I'm trying to insert words with apostrophes, and whenever there is one in my list, the apostrophe is treated like a single quotation mark. Oracle is thus adding a backslash automatically even though I didn't have one in the original insert values.

Example:

INSERT INTO DICTIONNAIRE (Mot) VALUES ('s\'ensuivre');

was originally

INSERT INTO DICTIONNAIRE (Mot) VALUES ('s'ensuivre');

Is there a way to treat the apostrophe differently than the single quotations surrounding the values?

> Original question:
>
> I want to insert a backslash as a string:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO Dictionnaire (Mot,Definition) VALUES ('abasourdir','v. tr.\\n Ahurir.');
> ```
>
> Is there a way to prevent the **backslash** from doing what it
>   normally does, that is: "escaping a single character or symbol", and
>   have the DBMS treat it like a simple string?
>
> set define off; doesn't work.
>
> Thanks!

Comment: Is a doube Backslash not working?

Comment: Your statement should work, backslash IS NOT escaping character in SQL insert. What SQL client are you using?

Comment: Working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2cf2d/1

Comment: @mr_eclair Unless the escape character is set to `'\'`

Comment: Are you writing SQL scripts or are you passing queries from another language? If the second, there's almost always a way to *parametrise* your queries so that you can pass data naturally and not have to deal with converting/escaping your data.

Comment: The problem wasn't the backslash finally. The backslashs are added whenever there is an apostrophe in my original text. Which is undesirable. Example:
INSERT INTO DICTIONNAIRE (Mot) VALUES ('s\'ensuivre');
was originally
INSERT INTO DICTIONNAIRE (Mot) VALUES ('s'ensuivre');
I posted an answer below to explain further.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to insert a backslash as a string: INSERT INTO Dictionnaire (Mot,Definition) VALUES ('abasourdir','v. tr.\n Ahurir.');

**Backslash will work as escape character only if you set the escape character as backslash**, or use the **ESCAPE command in the individual SQL statement.** Lest you should be able to insert it like any other character.

Use **two backslashes** *instead* of a **single backslash**.

For example, I have set the escape character as **set escape '\'**:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(a number, b VARCHAR2(10));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> set escape '\'
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(1, '\\');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(2, '\\n');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A B
---------- ----------
         1 \
         2 \n

SQL>
```

> Is there a way to prevent the backslash from doing what it normally does, that is: "escaping a single character or symbol", and have the DBMS treat it like a simple string?

Then don't use backslash to escape. Set **any other character** as an **escape character**.

For example, I will use **forward slash as escape character instead of backslash:**

```
SQL> DROP TABLE t PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(a number, b VARCHAR2(10));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> set escape '/'
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(1, '\');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(2, '\n');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(2, '/n');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A B
---------- ----------
         1 \
         2 \n
         2 n

SQL>
```

So, as you can see, only the forward slash was used to escape, not the backslash.

For that matter, you could use any other character to escape as well:

```
SQL> set escape '#'
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(1, '\');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(2, '\n');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(2, '#n');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A B
---------- ----------
         1 \
         2 \n
         2 n

SQL>
```

So, you can see that `'#'` was used as an escape character. Backslash had no affect.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Dictionnaire(MOT VARCHAR2(20),Definition varchar2(40));

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.71
```

This is if you want the quotes also, if you want just the back slash then see other insert,

```
SQL> INSERT INTO Dictionnaire (Mot,Definition) VALUES ('abasourdir','v. tr.''\''n Ahurir.');

1 row created.


Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> select * from Dictionnaire ;

MOT                  DEFINITION
-------------------- ----------------------------------------
abasourdir           v. tr.'\'n Ahurir.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01


SQL> INSERT INTO Dictionnaire (Mot,Definition) VALUES ('abasourdir','v. tr.\n Ahurir.');

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> select * from Dictionnaire ;

MOT                  DEFINITION
-------------------- ----------------------------------------
abasourdir           v. tr.'\'n Ahurir.
abasourdir           v. tr.\n Ahurir.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to treat the apostrophe differently than the single quotations surrounding the values?

```
INSERT INTO DICTIONNAIRE (Mot) VALUES ('s'ensuivre');
```

Yes, to INSERT a single quote in a value, simply double it.

```
INSERT INTO DICTIONNAIRE (Mot) VALUES ('s''ensuivre');
```

Comment: Oh.. I have a list of 27,700 words taken from a Dictionary text file. I cannot realistically edit and double every apostrophe instance. Do you see another solution?

Comment: @VincentLabrecque In that case the best option might be to write a client-side app (in your language of choice with an Oracle driver), and INSERT those values via a prepared statement.  The prepared statement should automatically escape-out special characters like apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured out that the problem wasn't coming from the backslash. The problem is a single quotation mark problem. I'm trying to insert words with apostrophes, and whenever there is one in my list, the apostrophe is treated like a single quotation mark. Oracle is thus adding a backslash automatically even though I didn't have one in the original insert values.

Example:

INSERT INTO DICTIONNAIRE (Mot) VALUES ('s\'ensuivre');

was originally

INSERT INTO DICTIONNAIRE (Mot) VALUES ('s'ensuivre');

Is there a way to treat the apostrophe differently than the single quotations surrounding the values?

Comment: Also, StackOverflow really isn't a discussion forum.  For something like this, you should edit your question and add this information.